# Changing the mongo image version from 3.6 to 3.4 (downgrade) results in error

Tags: mongodb, docker

I was using the mongo3.4 image and changed it to version 3.6 and started the service using `docker compose up mongo`

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    ports:
      - 27020:27017
    volumes:
```

Now it worked however, if I try to change the image back to mongo3.4, I get the following error:

```
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.686+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1681378580:686101][7:0x7f7d24753d40], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 2/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.688+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1681378580:688289][7:0x7f7d24753d40], txn-recover: WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.688+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1681378580:688307][7:0x7f7d24753d40], txn-recover: This may be due to the log files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.688+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1681378580:688312][7:0x7f7d24753d40], txn-recover: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.688+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1681378580:688325][7:0x7f7d24753d40], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.698+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 277
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.699+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.699+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.699+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.699+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.699+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
compose-mono-mongo-1  | 2023-04-13T09:36:20.699+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
compose-mono-mongo-1 exited with code 100
```

Is there a way for me to change the mongo image back to version 3.4?

**EDIT 1:** I had to delete the volume of the mongo container and restart the container with old version 3.4 for it to work. Be careful as this will result in data loss!

PS: connecting to the 3.6 mongo will require adding the `--bind_ip_all` flag to the mongo command [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76031379/connection-issues-to-mongodb-after-upgrade-and-or-data-restore-from-3-4-to-3-6)

Comment: I wonder, why you can't use 3.6. It's rather old itself, anyway.

Comment: Yes I was testing upgrading the mongo instance locally so I saw that it worked and wanted to revert the change.