# Connection issues to Mongodb after upgrade and/or data restore from 3.4 to 3.6

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker.

I am trying to update the mongo version for my local machine. I noticed that when I update the image from version (from 3.4 to 3.6 in docker-compose.yml) then although the mongo image starts, no clients (my app and studio3T) can connect to the new image (get connection timeouts).

Another method I tried is creating two new clean containers (one version 3.4 and the other 3.6 with both having same credentials) and getting a dump from 3.4 and copying it to the 3.6 container and doing a restore. The restore worked however when I tried to connect to the 3.6 database using studio3T, I got a connection issue again.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4
    ports:
      - 27020:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo-test:/data/db
  mongo-new:
    image: mongo:3.6
    ports:
      - 27021:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo-test-new:/data/db
volumes:
  mongo-test:
  mongo-test-new:
```

My dump contained one small document.

I am quite lost. How come something so simple isn’t possible?

**EDIT 1:** Here's the error log:

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27021] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketReadException): Prematurely reached end of stream

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27021, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
```

EDIT 2: Adding docker logs

```
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.545+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=f7bff9e5afa8
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.23
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: d352e6a4764659e0d0350ce77279de3c1f243e5c
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.546+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:54.547+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3417M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.610+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1681700335:610320][7:0x7f24b4718a40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 3/4480
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.611+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1681700335:611263][7:0x7f24b4718a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 4
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.696+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1681700335:696453][7:0x7f24b4718a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 4
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.744+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1681700335:744249][7:0x7f24b4718a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.762+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.772+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.773+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] listening via socket bound to 127.0.0.1
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.773+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] listening via socket bound to /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:55.773+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
test-mongo-new-1  | 2023-04-17T02:58:56.011+0000 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect on the right port? From your host you'd use `localhost:27021` to connect to the 3.6 container. Within the docker network it would be `mongo-new:27017`

Comment: yes, I'm connecting to the correct port

Comment: Do you get any logs from the MongoDB server side?

Comment: I've added the logs in an edit

Comment: No, those are your client-side logs. Check the logs from the MongoDB container. See https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mongo/README.md#container-shell-access-and-viewing-mongodb-logs

Comment: I am running my application via `mongod --auth` and connecting to it via studio3T Legacy authentication mode with the username and password which are the same across the 2 containers

Comment: Added docker logs

Comment: That warning about the `localhost` binding sounds relevant. It's not clear from your question how either container is configured with credentials or network settings. Are there some environment variables or command suffixes that you have omitted?

Comment: There are no network settings, only user settings that I've ommited which are creating the same users for both mongo versions. I'm not doing anything extra for the new mongo version which is why I cannot figure out why I'm getting the warning about `localhost`

Comment: Perhaps try adding `command: --bind_ip_all` in `docker-compose.yml`. See https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mongo/README.md#customize-configuration-without-configuration-file

Comment: That worked, but why isn't that necessary for 3.4?

Comment: Ah I see, version 3.6 had a new security patch: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#patch-releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the container logs...

> ```
> WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
>          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
> ```

See [Compatibility Changes in MongoDB 3.6](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/)

> When bound only to the localhost, these MongoDB 3.6 binaries can only accept connections from clients (including the [`mongo`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo) shell, other members in your deployment for replica sets and sharded clusters) that are running on the same machine. Remote clients cannot connect to the binaries bound only to localhost.

Unfortunately, this means you won't be able to connect from outside the container by default.

The simplest fix is to bind on all available network interfaces by adding a `command` suffix

```yaml
mongo-new:
  image: mongo:3.6
  ports:
    - 27021:27017
  volumes:
    - mongo-test-new:/data/db
  command: --bind_ip_all
```

See [Customize configuration without configuration file](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mongo/README.md#customize-configuration-without-configuration-file)